# Can I use one routers IP blocking feature behind another router connected to the internet?

Tags: router, security, ip, bridge, blocking

Situation:

My ISP's router (Sky Q) which I have to use to connect to the internet has terrible security features.  I would like to be able to block specific IP's on my home network from connecting to the internet but this is not possible with the Q box.

Potential Solution:

A friend gave me his old TP-Link W8960N which can do IP blocking.  Can I use the TP Links IP blocking feature in conjunction with the Q router providing internet access?

Im assuming it would have to function as a bridge or proxy type thing but Im really not sure where to go from there and would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. I recently had to get rid of the SkyQ router as it was far too bad at pretty much everything. You can replace the skyq router with a router that can send dhcp option 61 - Not many do this but all draytek routers can.

I won't go into details regarding option 61 but the string you need to send is

dhcp-client-identifier "1234567890ab@skydsl|1234567890abcdef",dhcp-class-identifier "7.16a4N_UNI|PCBAFAST2504Nv1.0"

Comment: Thanks mate, That'll save me banging my head again st a wall for a few hours!  Gonna get a 2nd hand Draytek.

Comment: Mark this question as answered, and reply to this comment again if you get stuck with the dhcp option thing - May be able to help

Comment: All good, realised I was overthinking it as usual and I can just use UFW to deny access to a specific IP.  Thanks again :)